# How to upload .txt file to server in service portal serviceNow?

Tags: javascript, servicenow, servicenow-rest-api

I tried to upload the the .txt file using service Portal ServiceNow? can any one help with the same??

Null File get uploaded and it is not showing on u_table_name record also.

Comment: Could add a link to the api reference ou precise your action in order people to help you ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.